# How to say "make it sound like〜"?

Tags: grammar, translation, word-choice, syntax

For example,

"Don't make it sound/seem like I am doing something wrong"

Or

"My teacher makes it sound like tomorrow's test will be difficult"

I tried,

"私は悪いことをするように言わないで"

Or

"私は悪いことをすると言わないで"

But the above translation seems more direct as in "don't *say* that I am doing something wrong" rather than "don't *make it seem like*".

Can そう be used in any way here?

Answer (score 1):

> Don't make it sound/seem like I am doing something wrong"
>
> 私は悪いことをするように言わないで

That's basically right except は should be が there and する should probably be している.

私が悪いことをしているように見えるようにしないで。

> 私は悪いことをすると言わないで

Again you need が in there

私が何か悪いことをしたようにいうのをやめてくれ

or something.

Comment: Thanks! As for the second sentence, does the なんか suggest the "seems" part?

Comment: No, you said "doing something wrong" and the 何か corresponds to "something".

Comment: Got it! So is this correct? 先生は明日のテストが難しいように見えるようにしました